# Is there a proper way to let users know about known issues

Tags: mobile-application

I am working on an Android application and I have some known issues (both platform related and "won't fix" issues).

1. Is there a proper way to let users know about these known issues?
2. How visible should this list be?

Just to clarify: I don't expect these issues to be common (or major).

**Edit**: more info

Example issues:

1. Platform: Android has a backup system for apps, but it only runs on Android's [schedule](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#BackupSchedule) (when certain conditions are met). If the user made some changes *after* an update, uninstall and later reinstall he will lose the changes he has made after the update.
2. Won't fix: there's a notification that is shown to the user if the application goes to the background (configuration related notification). There is a state of the app where this notification will not be sent (although it should have been sent).

Layout: the main application is a map with a drawer - this is the current layout, but this may change.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? As in, what exactly are these issues and the layout (list/grid) you currently have?

Comment: I think I've seen something like this once or twice... IIRC, it was tucked into a menu around the sort of place you might get _**About**_, _**Contact**_, _**Terms of Use**_ and _**Licenses**_ pages.

Comment: @TripeHound sounds interesting, I'll see what other answers come up.

Answer (score 3):

As a user of an app, I'd not expect these in the app itself. For example, if your app crashes during launch because of a known issue, you wouldn't even be able to view the list. I'd expect a support website to be listed in the Play Store (or App Store for iOS apps). The Play Store offers the option (under Store Listing -> Contact -> Website) to specify a link, e.g. for the official [Stack Exchange app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) it's just https://stackexchange.com:

[image]

Apple's App Store has a dedicated URL for app support.

Since it's something that you probably want to update without needing to publish a new build of the app (especially for an iOS app with its review process), consider using a website for this, and (optionally) add a link to this website somewhere in the menu (or maybe in the FAQ section if you have one).

Comment: Having a link _somewhere else_ would be good (for the crash-on-launch case), but **(a)** I would say _known_ reasons for crashing on launch _aren't_ minor issues and _shouldn't_ be "won't fix", and **(b)** assuming you _can_ open the app, being able to see the list in-app (or, at least, have a link to the appropriate web page in-app) would still be useful.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense, however currently I don't think I'll create a site, since this app is intended to be free and I don't think I'll invest in a site (time and money)